# open source java IDEs which support code complete

Tags: java, ide, code-completion

What I have known of are eclipse , netbeans and  JavaSideKick for jedit. Are there other alternatives?

Please let me know cause it really helps me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Of the various IDEs I've tried, my recommendation would be to go with either NetBeans or Eclipse (I prefer NetBeans, but there are some things, like Android for example, that require Eclipse).

Answer (score 3):

[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) has free [Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html) version.

[Here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) is IntelliJ IDEA editions comparison matrix.

[Instruction how to check out & build community edition](http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983225).

Comment: thanks. Any clue how can I access the souce code for this version?

Comment: I've added link to instruction in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[JCreator](http://www.jcreator.com/)